# ¿Cómo asignarle un valor a un caracter? C++

Tags: c++, ascii

Quisiera hacer algo parecido a la tabla ascii, pero a mi antojo, yo darle el valor a cada caracter, he intentado varios tipos de conversiones desde darle valores al inicio a las variables, hasta haciendo el cambio.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Y cual seria la pregunta en este caso? no queda claro que esperas que te contestemos.. tene en cuenta que debes aclarar un problema puntual.

Comment: Si has hecho varios intentos no veo motivo para no publicar alguno en la pregunta. Así tendremos una base sobre la que empezar a darte soluciones

Answer (score 0):

este pequeño código te permite guardar valores con un numero que tu lo asignes. Aunque solo te permite imprimir uno de los valores ingresados.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
char letra;
int n, n1, valores, a;
char valor [255];
main (){
    cout << "Ingrese cuantos valores desea usar:";
    cin >> valores;
    for (a=1; a<=valores; a++){
        cout << "Ingrese el valor a usar\t";
        cin >> n;
        cout << "Letra a guardar:\t";
        cin >> letra;
        valor [n] = letra;
    }
    cout << "Que letra desea imprimir\t";
    cin >> n1;
    cout << valor [n1];
}
```

Espero sea de tu ayuda.